# React native background process

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to figure out how to run background service in react native (Android).
Is it possible to run code (e.g. socket listener) while app is running in background or not. I created something simple to determine that, but seems like it's not working that way. Any help?

```
    class HolaProject extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {holaText: "0"};
      var self = this;

      setTimeout(() => {
        self.setState({holaText: "after 10 seconds, works!"})
      }, 10000);
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <DrawerLayoutAndroid renderNavigationView={() => <Text>React Native</Text>}>
        <Text>{this.state.holaText}</Text>
        <ProgressBarAndroid />
      </DrawerLayoutAndroid>
    );
  }
};
```

Comment: The same for ios somebody knows ?

Comment: @ButuzGOL : Did anyone find the solution for it?

Answer (score 1):

**On Android**

Yes, it can be done. Check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25221510/how-to-use-socket-io-with-background-service-on-android) for more information. Basically, you have to enable a notification to "wake" the device when receiving information.

**On iOS**

Yes, it can be done too, but through hacks.
Check these links on SO to have a deeper understanding of these hacks

> Play a silent sound and set the background mode to audio. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5840365/how-can-an-ios-app-keep-a-tcp-connection-alive-indefinitely-while-in-the-backgro) for more information on the matter.
>
> Use VoIP services. Check more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30680975/how-to-handle-a-tcp-connection-in-background-for-poker-app-server-client-app) but it'll require you justify a VoIP service to Apple.