# React Native Background Socket IO

Tags: android, ios, react-native, socket.io

I'm working on a video call app (using react native webrtc), and I want to maintain an open socket in the background that would listen for video calls, and push notification in response, so that the user could answer.

I've seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34369932/react-native-background-process), but I wanted to know if now, there's a better solution for this, and if not, I hope you could direct me to a more react-native guided solution, that would help me understand how to achieve what I want.

Thanks.

Comment: were you able to figure it out?

Comment: @Akshaykomarla Firebase Cloud Messaging: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/

I also found a good react native library for that.

Comment: which react library ?

Comment: Google is your friend: https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm

Comment: i tried to connect socket when notification received. but it doesn't work