# What is the React Native library I can use to run a task in background periodically (even though the app is closed)?

Tags: react-native, background-process

I want to run a function as a **background service** for both iOS and Android platforms. It should **run periodically (for every 1 hour)**, even though the **app is closed**.

Comment: Question has been answered. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34369932/react-native-background-process#35598632